# C# Winforms: How to update scrollbar of Listbox while dragging scrollbar with mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have Listbox with initial number of items and it has vertical scrollbar.

I have implemented following behavior: if I move (holding left mouse button) scroll to the end of scrollbar then some number of a new items are added to the Listbox control. The problem is that scrollbar of Listbox is updated (with respect to the new listbox items count) only if I do left mouse button up. But I need it to be updated immediately after new items are added to the listbox and without need to stop dragging mouse down.

Example of right behavior that I want: https://www.google.com/fonts.
As you can see there, if you dragging scroll down it is immediatly updated and jumps on a number of positions up each time new items are loaded.

So, my question is: how to correctly implement such behavior without using 3rd party listbox controls?

EDIT:

In my Form1 form control I do load new items by testing scroll position:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ...
        var timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 500;
        timer.Tick += TimerCheckForListItemsScrollDown;
        timer.Start();
    }

    private void TimerCheckForListItemsScrollDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count < 1)
        {
            return;
        }
        int visibleCount = listBox1.ClientSize.Height /
            ((MyListItem)(listBox1.Items[0])).ItemHeight + 1;

        if (listBox1.TopIndex == 0)
            return;


        if (listBox1.TopIndex + visibleCount > listBox1.Items.Count - 5)
        {
            InsertNextBucketOfListItems();
            //I try to invalidate and refresh control but with no positive results, while I hold left mouse button down nothing happens.
           listBox1.Invalidate();
           listBox1.Refresh();
        }

    }
```

EDIT 2:
I added my solution below.

Comment: Have you tried anything? This place is more for specific problems with code you tried than generic direction, which is more what google is for.

Comment: I added some code sample from the project and there is what I did, but with no results. Now I just try to find the right direction how should I fix my problem.

Comment: Pretty important to recognize UI that was made to be operated with a touch screen.  A program that makes the mouse fall off the desk or the finger off the trackpad is not useful.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I discovered a solution for my problem. The main idea is to generate WM_LBUTTONUP event on listbox control.

That is how I do that:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern void mouse_event(uint dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

    private void TimerCheckForListItemsScrollDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.Items.Count < 1)
       {
            return;
       }
       int visibleCount = listBox1.ClientSize.Height /
            ((MyListItem)(listBox1.Items[0])).ItemHeight + 1;

       if (listBox1.TopIndex == 0)
           return;


       if (listBox1.TopIndex + visibleCount > listBox1.Items.Count - 5)
       {
           InsertNextBucketOfListItems();
           //Now is the trick
           var p = Cursor.Position;
           //0004- mouse Up
           mouse_event((uint)0x0004, (uint)p.X, (uint)p.Y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
       }

   }
```

Since that scroll is updated each time when new items are loaded. But I didn't realized how to continue scrolling without need to release mouse button after scroll is updated.